# Spring's load-time weaving of spring managed beans, is there a conflict?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

My project already had some aspects working using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` and using the aspectj style @Aspect annotations. But because we needed to advise some classes outside our control we wanted to introduce the Spring-style load time weaving for Tomcat as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3....tml#aop-aj-ltw

My LTW configuration seems to be correct insofar as I have turned on the verbose and debug weaver options and I am seeing lines like this in my catalina.out

```
2013-11-28 13:17:57,167+0000 [INFO ] org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContext LoadTimeWeaver [main] - Using a reflective load-time weaver for class loader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat .TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@53ea0105] info register aspect com.anon.profiling.aspect.MyAspect
...
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@273d1402] debug not weaving 'org.quartz.SimpleTrigger'
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@273d1402] debug not weaving 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory'
...
```

The class I want to instrument is in a package with several others and I can see other classes in that package being debugged in the same way as not being woven. But about half of the classes (including the one I'm interested in...) aren't mentioned at all - either as being not woven or ignored or otherwise. Digging into it a little I think I spot a pattern that the classes being ignored are managed by Spring: either by being declared in an applicationContext.xml or being injected into another class with an @Inject.

Is it the case that a spring managed bean will not be loaded by the TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader for weaving? Is there something I need to add to my config to enable it?

-- Rachel

Edit:  In response to @gadget

aop.xml

```
<aspectj>

    <!-- "includes" required in order to use both Spring AOP as well as AspectJ Load Time Weaving where Proxied classes are not possible eg. MarkLogicClient -->
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true">
        <!-- only weave classes in the following packages -->
        <include within="mycompany..*"/>
        <include within="javax.*"/>
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mycompany.appname"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <context:load-time-weaver/>


    <!-- bean declarations normally here, removed for brevity -->

</beans>
```

web.xml (apologies, it's a bit long but i didnt want to remove anything in case it was significant)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>appname</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servicestatus</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>mycompany.appname.security.ResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WadlGeneratorConfig</param-name>
            <param-value>mycompany.appname.jersey.Isite2WadlGeneratorConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servicestatus</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servicestatus</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>logging</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>propertiesConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/propertiesConfigContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>utf8ValidatingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>mycompany.appname.filter.Utf8ValidatingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>utf8ValidatingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>timingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>mycompany.appname.filter.TimingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>timingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>mycompany.appname.log.EnvironmentalPropertiesLog4jContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Most probably you are using multiple Spring contexts with different classloaders and the weaver agent has not been setup on all of them. Could you post your xml configs, or describe the hierarchy?

Comment: Can add aop.xml and applicationContext.xml, would you need to see any others?  web.xml, pom.xml?

Comment: aop.xml and applicationContext.xml would be useful and web.xml just to see how you load the context

Comment: @gadget: Added the web.xml too